# How use to_char in nvl()

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
V_MAX:=NVL(CREAR_DEPART(V_NOMB),TO_CHAR('the value is null'));

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_MAX);
```

The function gives me a type number

How can I use `nvl` to get a value in `varchar2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That string already is a ... well, *string*, you don't `to_char` it.

```
SQL> with test (v_nomb) as
  2    (select to_number(null) from dual)
  3  select nvl(to_char(v_nomb), 'the value is null') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
-----------------
the value is null

SQL>
```

Or, in your case,

```
V_MAX := NVL(to_char(CREAR_DEPART(V_NOMB)), 'the value is null');
```

---

As you commented, function returns a `number`. Or - in order to capture it with a `NVL` - let it return `null`.

```
SQL> create or replace function crear_depart(par_nomb in number)
  2  return number is
  3  begin
  4    return null;
  5  end;
  6  /

Function created.

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    v_max  varchar2(20);
  3    v_nomb number := 2;
  4  begin
  5    v_max := nvl(to_char(crear_depart(v_nomb)), 'the value is null');
  6    dbms_output.put_line('v_max = ' || v_max);
  7  end;
  8  /
v_max = the value is null

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error : character to number conversion

Comment: Aha; the function seems to be returning a number, so - it has to have to_char, not the *string* (the 2nd parameter to the NVL function). Fixed; have a look, please.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work, if I change 'the value is null' to 0 it does work, but I would like a string back

Comment: I forgot to say that the function gives me a type number

Comment: OK; I created an example with a function that returns a number and the way it should be used in a PL/SQL block, trying to mimic what you posted so far. It *works* for me. If that's not what you have, please, post similar test case (by editing your question! Not as a comment!) so that we could see how it looks like.